# python copy files to a network location on Windows without mapping a drive

Tags: python, file, networking, copy, unc

I am running python in a non interactive session on windows and therefore I cannot map a network drive.

Most of what I have researched on here and through google everyone suggests mapping a network drive and copying the files that way.

On linux I would facilitate this with an smbmount but unfortunately the software I am working with is tied to windows.

Are there any options for interacting with files via a UNC path?

Comment: have you tried creating a file object with the unc path? i.e. f = open('\\server\dir\file.name'); f.write(strings)?

Comment: I use UNC paths all the time in Python on Windows. They work fine.

Answer (score 31):

Personally, I've never had difficulties getting Python to simply recognize `\\\\<server>\\path\\to\\directory\\`. The annoying part is that for every "\" in the win. path, there needs to be 2 in python.

Comment: ... unless you use raw strings, which you should.  :-)

Comment: or os.sep. uglier but less of a hassle.

Comment: how do I authenticate to that share with credentials?

Comment: @kindall Sure, but for that matter, I shouldn't really be using Windows either. Within a week I'm all *nix! WHOO-HOO!

Comment: @kindall But remember that raw strings won't let you do the trailing backslash - that always screws me up.

Answer (score 11):

First get access to the network share with "NET USE" - without Drive letter, like:

```
winCMD = 'NET USE ' + networkPath + ' /User:' + user + ' ' + password
subprocess.Popen(winCMD, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

As in here (but without specifying Drive letter):
[What is the best way to map windows drives using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271317/what-is-the-best-way-to-map-windows-drives-using-python)

Then copy the file/directory with shutil.copy, like:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy2(networkPath + 'sourceDir/sourceFile', 'destDir/destFile')
```

As in here:
[How do I copy a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)