# psexec run python script passed from host

Tags: python, python-2.7, psexec

I am trying to run a python script on a remote computer via psexec.  I am able to connect and run python.exe with the following:

```
C:\test>psexec \\192.168.X.X -u domain\administrator -p password -i C:\Anaconda\python.exe
```

The path to python.exe is the path on the remote machine.  This opens a python window on the remote machine - all good.

I want to now pass a python script from the host machine to run on the remote.  This script is on the host machine in C:\test\test.py.  I tried

```
psexec \\192.168.X.X -u domain\administrator -p password -i "C:\Anaconda\python.exe" -c C:\test\test.py
```

and get:

```
C:\Anaconda\python.exe exited on 192.168.X.X with error code 1.
```

I also tried-c test.py without the full path, and got a similar error.  My thought is the remote application cannot find C:\test\test.py.  I want to be able to pass the script from the host machine.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to access a python script on a shared drive from the remote computer and host, and so by copying to the share from the host and reading from the share on the remote machine i had a suitable workaround (the -i switch is not required).

```
psexec \\remote_machine_name -u domain\user -p pswrd -i C:/Anaconda/python.exe \\server\share\test\test.py
```

Related:  if you are running on windows and writing to a UNC path from a python script i.e test.py above, helpful path formatting help:

[python copy files to a network location on Windows without mapping a drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224541/python-copy-files-to-a-network-location-on-windows-without-mapping-a-drive)

Answer (score 0):

If the `.py` extension has been associated with the Python installation on the remote machine, you may be able to run your Python script by simply removing the Python executable from the command line:

```
psexec \\192.168.X.X -u domain\administrator -p password -i -c C:\test\test.py
```

Please note that I have not tried this as I don't presently have access to a remote machine, so I can't guarantee that it will work.

The line

```
psexec \\192.168.X.X -u domain\administrator -p password -i "C:\Anaconda\python.exe" -c C:\test\test.py
```

may be trying to run the command `"C:\Anaconda\python.exe" -c C:\test\test.py` on the remote machine.  In other words, Python may be interpreting the `-c` switch, rather than PsExec.  The Python switch `-c` specifies some Python code to run, and of course a filename is not valid Python code:

```
C:\Users\Luke>python -c "print 2 + 2"
4

C:\Users\Luke>python -c C:\test\test.py
  File "<string>", line 1
    C:\test\test.py
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\Luke>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```

Comment: I associated .py with the the python.exe on the remote machine.  Removing the executable from the command line fails with error:   PsExec could not start test.py on 192.168.X.X:
The system cannot find the file specified.