# python subprocess code not running psexec

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, psexec

The below code hangs:

```
import subprocess

def user():
    program = subprocess.Popen(['psexec','\\\\<computername>','/ACCEPTEULA','-u',
                                'NATIONAL\\<user>','-p','<password>','qwinsta'], 
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout,stderr) = program.communicate()
    stdout_lines = stdout.split("\n")
    return stdout_lines

output = user() 

for line in output:
    print(line)
```

when I run the psexec command in cmd it works fine.

Comment: does your password contain backslashes?

Comment: works with a simple `dir` command. Well, sort of: I only get the first line of the output!!!

Comment: no backslashes in the password - can this be done by a simpler block of code. I want to remotely see users who are logged on.

Comment: what about `psloggedon` then ?

Comment: are you sure about the escaping of backslashes? Python does not need those (your string becomes `\\\\<computername>`), also [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963625/psexec-run-python-script-passed-from-host) psexec does not need those

Comment: thanks you! - psloggedon worked

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

def user():

    program = subprocess.Popen(['psloggedon','\\\\<servername>'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                          (stdout,stderr) = program.communicate()
                          stdout_lines = stdout.split("\n")
    return stdout_lines
output = user() 
for line in output:    print(line)
```