# using exec.command in go lang for net use

Tags: windows, go

I have a requirement to map the drives in Windows using go and found this link to be useful 
[What is the best way to map windows drives using golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277465/what-is-the-best-way-to-map-windows-drives-using-golang)

When I tried to use the code given here, I ran into this error

```
exec: "net use": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

I verified that the bin folder of go is in the PATH variable.  I also tried by running it like

```
cmd, err := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "NET USE", "T:", \\SERVERNAME\C$, "/PERSISTENT").CombinedOutput()
```

but I get this error:

```
exit status 1 You used an option with an invalid value.
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every argument to `exec.Command()` is used as a single argument, so:

```
exec.Command(... "NET USE", ..)
```

Will mean that `NET USE` is passed as a single argument, which is the same as doing this from the command line:

```
cmd /c "net use"
```

Which means it will try to find `net use.exe`, instead of passing the argument `use` to `net.exe`.

So the correct way is:

```
exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "net", "use", "Q:, `\\SERVER\SHARE`, "/user:Alice pa$$word", "/P")
```

The `cmd /c` part probably isn't needed, but I don't have a Windows machine to verify.

Also note how I used backticks (`` ` ``) for `\\SERVER\SHARE` instead of `"`, so you don't have to double up the backslashes.

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker. This worked and also cmd is not required. The mistake I was doing is with /P.
exec.Command("net use", "Q:, `\\SERVER\SHARE`, "/user:Alice pa$$word", "/P:YES")
It requires P:YES instead of just /P